# Separating character columns with common prefixes

Tags: r

I have a data frame like

```
 ddf <- data.frame(
  X = c("Fruit.Apple", "Fruit.Pear", 
        "Car.Mazda", "Car.Toyota", 
        "North.American.City.Chicago", "North.American.City.Ottawa", "North American.City.Toronto", "North.American.City.Los.Angeles", "Unique.Snowflake"), 
  Y = runif(9)  # doesn't matter
  )

                            X         Y
1                     Fruit.Apple 0.2655087
2                      Fruit.Pear 0.3721239
3                       Car.Mazda 0.5728534
4                      Car.Toyota 0.9082078
5     North.American.City.Chicago 0.2016819
6      North.American.City.Ottawa 0.8983897
7     North.American.City.Toronto 0.9446753
8 North.American.City.Los.Angeles 0.6607978
9                Unique.Snowflake 0.6291140
```

and I want:

```
                  X.1              X.2         Y
1               Fruit            Apple 0.2655087
2               Fruit             Pear 0.3721239
3                 Car            Mazda 0.5728534
4                 Car           Toyota 0.9082078
5 North.American.City          Chicago 0.2016819
6 North.American.City           Ottawa 0.8983897
7 North.American.City          Toronto 0.9446753
8 North.American.City      Los.Angeles 0.6607978
9                <NA> Unique.Snowflake 0.6291140
```

I'm not totally convinced my problem is soluble, but it seems to have a pattern. I'm completing stumped for a solution. It would be easy if prefixes were easily separated but as the `North.American.City` example shows, sometimes the prefix contains the separating character. It would be relatively straightforward if the suffix didn't contain the `.` but `Los.Angeles` shouldn't be separated. I also only want true prefixes to appear in `X.1` as I've demonstrated with `Unique.Snowflake`. My only thought is to create new column of all text between `.` using `gsub("(.*)\\..*$", "\\1", ...)` and some nested for-loops to work out which ones are prefixes, but there must be a better way.

Comment: Do you have a list of valid prefixes to work with?

Comment: No. A prefix is simply the largest prefix that is common to more than one row in `X`. A prefix will always terminate with `.` however.

Comment: Sorry. I've decided this is not insoluble, but rather is too complex (and therefore off-topic for SO). You are asking us to provide a set of separation rules that have a human level intelligence behind them. Voting to close as "too broad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. This is a lot of messy code but it does the job. I'm sure others can come up with more elegant solutions.

```
#sample vector for splitting
X = c("Fruit.Apple", "Fruit.Pear", 
    "Car.Mazda", "Car.Toyota", 
    "North.American.City.Chicago", "North.American.City.Ottawa", 
    "North.American.City.Toronto", "North.American.City.Los.Angeles",
    "Unique.Snowflake"
)

#split on "." and prepare candidates
parts<-strsplit(X,".", fixed=T)
scores<-lapply(parts, function(p) {
    lp<-length(p)
    list(
        c("",sapply(seq.int(p), function(x) paste(p[1:x], collapse="."))),
        c(sapply(seq.int(p), function(x) paste(p[x:lp], collapse=".")),""),
        seq.int(lp+1)
    )
});

#now combine considerations
options<-do.call(rbind, lapply(seq.int(scores), function(i) 
    data.frame(
        item=i, 
        prefix=scores[[i]][[1]], 
        suffix=scores[[i]][[2]],
        depth=scores[[i]][[3]]))
    )
#now add the freq score across all categories
options$freq=ave(rep.int(1,nrow(options)),options$prefix, FUN=length)

#finally, select the longest prefix combination that occurs >1 times
best<-do.call(rbind, by(options, options$item, function(x) {
    x[order(x$freq<=1, -x$depth), ][1,]
}))
best[,2:3];
```

And this results in

```
               prefix           suffix
1               Fruit            Apple
2               Fruit             Pear
3                 Car            Mazda
4                 Car           Toyota
5 North.American.City          Chicago
6 North.American.City           Ottawa
7 North.American.City          Toronto
8 North.American.City      Los.Angeles
9                     Unique.Snowflake
```

Comment: But is it general enogh for a dataset with thousands of combinations? The OP decided to add two more examples and your ad hoc rules do not look particularly general.

Comment: @BondedDust Which rules were added that you don't think i'll satisfy? It's actually pretty general. I would be more concerned about scalability. As long as the number of periods doesn't get huge, it should scale somewhat linearly for the most part though.

Comment: Maybe your coding was too subtle for my limited brain. Perhaps you should explain in more detail how the code works to distinguish "Fruit.Apple" from "Unique.Snowflake" and decide that one of them should be split and the other be unitary?

Comment: Messy but works on my (private) problem as well as the toy data. I was curious (I still am) whether there was a function or package for these sorts of tasks. Wasn't expecting such substantial work. Thanks!

Comment: @BondedDust it's this line `x[order(x$freq<=1, -x$depth), ][1,]`. `Unique` isn't a prefix because it only occurs once, but `Fruit` is because it occurs more than once.

Comment: @BondedDust Yes, as Hugh pointed out that's the magic line. Perhaps it would be useful to inspect the `options` data.frame. It looks at only those shared prefixes (freq>1) and picks the longest one (or the only one in the case of those that don't share). Everything else was build up to get to that point.

Comment: This solution would "fail" if you had something like North.American.State.New.Mexio and North.American.State.New.York. It would choose "North.American.State.New" for the prefix and "Mexico" and "York" for the suffix. But the goal of these commands is just to find the longest shared prefix possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ddf2 <- gsub("\\.([[:alpha:]]*)$", " \\1", ddf$X)
 data.frame( read.table(text=ddf2), Y=ddf$Y)
#------------
                   V1      V2         Y
1               Fruit   Apple 0.8097010
2               Fruit    Pear 0.6934737
3                 Car   Mazda 0.2143207
4                 Car  Toyota 0.5036963
5 North.American.City Chicago 0.7364826
6 North.American.City  Ottawa 0.8603377
7 North.American.City Toronto 0.4751705
```

(Your example construction code doesn't make the line with "snowflake. Nor
 do you describe why we would not split at the last period..)

Comment: Note the example of `Los.Angeles`

Comment: The example is noted ... however, _you_ are the one responsible for defining the rules. This is a coding site ; NOT an artificial intelligence site. If you want to provide an separation rule that has a certified collection of separation terms like "City", "Fruit", "Car", then please, by all means, provide them. As it is you are failing in your responsibilities.